# php giving a blank page, no errors

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I have the following part of an AJAX application, which gives no errors, but also nothing is displayed to the screen, so I am unsure of where the problem lies. Calling this page directly from a browser with ?cmd&id=1 should return, or even calling it without ?cmd should return the cmd error message.

edit: added test cases: I do get the cmd error message, but when I pass &id=1 (1 is a valid id), no html gets returned whatsoever, view source is completely blank. Have I used echo incorrectly or something similar?

edit2: added echo as first line: the first echo is not seen whatsoever

edit3: After going back to an older version and making all the changes again, I now get test charset output when calling with valid cmd and id paramters. The code I am using is identical to what is pasted below.

the code:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";    
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_GET["cmd"]))
  $cmd = $_GET["cmd"];
else
  die("You should have a 'cmd' parameter in your URL");

$id = $_GET["id"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
echo "test con";

if(!$con)
{
  die('Connection failed because of' .mysqli_connect_error());
  echo "test error";
}

//$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
$con->set_charset("utf8"));
echo "test charset";

if($cmd=="GetSALEData")
{
  echo "test cmdifloop";

  if ($getRecords = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM SALES WHERE PRODUCT_NO = ?"))
  {
    echo "test recordifloop";

    $getHtml = $con->prepare("SELECT PRODUCT_DESC FROM SALES WHERE PRODUCT_NO = ?");
    $getHtml->bind_param("s", $id);
    $getHtml->execute();
    $getHtml->bind_result($PRODUCT_DESC);

    $getRecords->bind_param("s", $id);
    $getRecords->execute(); 
    $getRecords->bind_result($PRODUCT_NO, $PRODUCT_NAME, $SUBTITLE, $CURRENT_PRICE, $START_PRICE,
                             $PRICE_COUNT, $QUANT_TOTAL, $QUANT_SOLD, $ACCESSSTARTS, $ACCESSENDS,
                             $ACCESSORIGIN_END, $USERNAME, $BEST_PRICEDER_ID, $FINISHED, $WATCH,
                             $BUYITNOW_PRICE, $PIC_URL, $PRIVATE_SALE, $SALE_TYPE, $ACCESSINSERT_DATE,
                             $ACCESSUPDATE_DATE, $CAT_DESC, $CAT_PATH, $COUNTRYCODE, $LOCATION,
                             $CONDITIONS, $REVISED, $PAYPAL_ACCEPT, $PRE_TERMINATED, $SHIPPING_TO,
                             $FEE_INSERTION, $FEE_FINAL, $FEE_LISTING, $PIC_XXL, $PIC_DIASHOW,
                             $PIC_COUNT, $ITEM_SITE_ID
                            ); 
    while ($getRecords->fetch()) 
    {
      $ccodes = array(  "1" => "USA",
                       "77" => "Germany",
                       "16" => "Austria",
                      "122" => "Luxemburg",
                      "193" => "Switzerland",
                     );

      $conditions = array( "0" => "USA",
                          "77" => "Germany",
                          "16" => "Austria",
                         );

      $country = $ccodes[$COUNTRYCODE];
      if ( $country == "" ) $country = "Not applicable";

      $columns = array('FINISHED', 'WATCH', 'PRIVATE_SALE', 'REVISED', 'PAYPAL_ACCEPT', 'PRE_TERMINATED', 'PIC_XXL', 'PIC_DIASHOW');

      foreach($columns as $column) {
        $$column = $row[$column] ? 'YES' : 'NO';
      }

      imageResize($PIC_URL, 250, 300);
      file_put_contents($id, file_get_contents($PIC_URL));

      $html = htmlentities(json_encode($PRODUCT_DESC));
      $shortDate = strftime("%d %m %Y", strtotime($ACCESSSTARTS));

      echo "<h1>".$PRODUCT_NAME."</h1>
<div id='leftlayer' class='leftlayer'>
<p><strong>Username: </strong>".$USERNAME."
<p><strong>PRODUCT Number: </strong>".$PRODUCT_NO."
<p><strong>Subtitle: </strong>".$SUBTITLE."
<p><strong>SALE Start: </strong>".$ACCESSSTARTS." 
<p><strong>SALE End: </strong>".$ACCESSENDS."
<p><strong>SALE Type: </strong>".$SALE_TYPE."
<p><strong>Category: </strong>".$CAT_DESC."
</div>
<div class='leftlayer2'>
  <p><strong>Condition: </strong> ".$CURRENT_PRICE."
  <p><strong>Total Items: </strong> ".$QUANT_TOTAL."
  <p><strong>Total Sales: </strong> ".$QUANT_SOLD."
  <p><strong>Start Price: &#8364</strong> ".$START_PRICE."
  <p><strong>Buyitnow Price: &#8364</strong> ".$BUYITNOW_PRICE."
  <p><strong>PRICEs: </strong> ".$PRICE_COUNT." 
  <p><strong>Revised: </strong> ".$REVISED."
</div>
<div class='leftlayer2'>
  <p><strong>Private: </strong> ".$PRIVATE_SALE."
  <p><strong>Finished: </strong> ".$FINISHED."
  <p><strong>Cancelled: </strong> ".$PRE_TERMINATED."
  <p><strong>Paypal: </strong> ".$PAYPAL_ACCEPT."
  <p><strong>Country: </strong> ". $country ."
  <p><strong>Location: </strong> ".$LOCATION."
  <p><strong>Shipping to: </strong> ". $country ."
</div>
<div id='rightlayer'>
 <img src='".$PIC_URL."' width='".$imageSize["width"]."' height='".$imageSize["height"]."'>
 <p><a href='#' onclick=\"makewindows(" . $html . "); return false;\">Click for full description </a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>";

    } 
  }

  function imageResize($imageURL, $maxWidth, $maxHeight)
  {
    $imageSize["width"] = 0;
    $imageSize["height"] = 0;

    $size = getimagesize($imageURL);
    if ($size) {
      $imageWidth  = $size[0];

      $imageHeight = $size[1];
      $wRatio = $imageWidth / $maxWidth;
      $hRatio = $imageHeight / $maxHeight;
      $maxRatio = max($wRatio, $hRatio);

      if ($maxRatio > 1) {
        $imageSize["width"] = $imageWidth / $maxRatio;
        $imageSize["height"] = $imageHeight / $maxRatio;
        return $imageSize;
      } else {
        $imageSize["width"] = $imageWidth;
        $imageSize["height"] = $imageHeight;
        return $imageSize;
      }
    } else {
      die(print_r(error_get_last()));
    }
  }

}
```

I apologize for the spacing, but it happens automatically when I press the code button.

Comment: Get rid of everything except the first die() line. Do you see any output?

Comment: i see the cmd error even with everything there

Comment: Try and put echo "test" line by line to see what is being outputted to the screen. Then we can further diagnose it. Also try and indent your code.

Comment: I put tests as you can see in the editied code, not one was printed to the screen.

Comment: i made your code readable for you...

Comment: @Josh, don't be insulted by d03boy's comment. EVERY programmer writes atrocious code at one point or another. Yes. the code is a little messy. But, you will get better with time. Your patterns of development will improve, etc.

Comment: I am not to insulted, but am eager to know better ways to do anything I am doing. I am aware I should indent and comment more, but I am far more concerned if there are better ways to do things.

Comment: The only output is if I omit cmd. Any other combination of cmd=anything and id=anything or one of the other all return blank.

Comment: update: I now get test charset; output, I am not sure what I changed?

Comment: Post a database dump of the table.  It'll be easier to test

Comment: I mean provide some sample data.  The script is working as far as I can test without database data.

Comment: Where is your closing ?>

Comment: @Jonathan- closing ?> is actually discouraged for a PHP-only file, at least by Zend: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.general

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis on line 22

This

```
$con->set_charset("utf8"));
```

Needs to be this

```
$con->set_charset("utf8");
```

Two debugging tips for the future.  For the first, you'll need shell access to your web host, or you'll need to install PHP locally on your development machine. If you're running Unix, you may already have it. Open a terminal and type

```
php -v
```

If you have it, you can check the syntax of a PHP file by doing

```
//on *nix
php yourfile.php

//or on windows
c:\path\to\php.exe yourfile.php
```

This will bail on gross syntax errors.  Also, google/search this site for "setup php locally tutorial" or something similar to learn how to get a full copy of A Webserver, mysql database and php running on your own machine.

The second suggestion, which will be easier if you install a local copy, is to check your error logs.  Even when PHP isn't displaying error messages, errors will still be logged to a file somewhere.  In your case, you'd have seen something like this in the log file

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in foo.php on line 22
```

Answer (score 14):

This will help you see your errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: still no errors are shown. I dont think it is a php error problem, just a logic problem or such.

Comment: to show parse errors, display_errors has to be enabled in a config file, not at run time

Comment: add this directive to you .htaccess if you want to catch parse errors

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra closing parenthesis here:

```
$con->set_charset("utf8"));
```

Comment: fixed, but it made no difference

Comment: This script runs fine for me after fixing this line, except that I don't have any records in my database.

Comment: My database definitely has data in it. I can paste the table information so you can use some test data?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a basic test of placing a print or echo statement immediately at the top of the script to test output?

```
<?php

  print "Test";

?>
```

I would also suggest using an `or die($msg)` catch after your connect attempt.

Would be fine for your case. Just as a starting-point. I do this from time to time when needed. Rather than assuming the issue is some massively-complex problem, it often times turns out to be unexpected condition in request variables, accessing wrong page, accessing right page at wrong time, etc.

Comment: Isnt my line if (!con) catching any errors? The fact that the page outputs an error if cmd is not passed must mean it is working in part yes?

Comment: I added echo "hello world" right after <?php and still nothing was output

Comment: @Josh - empty the document. ONLY have print "Hello World"; and try that.

Comment: Put  ?> at the end of the file just to humor me

Comment: hello world works when it is the only statement in the file. Putting ?> at the end made no difference.

Comment: I now get test charset displayed.

Answer (score 2):

May help:

1. Monitor the Web server log (like `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`)
2. Use Firebug and see in the Console the AJAX response coming from your script. The error may appear there

Comment: I have checked the error log, all is fine

I will investigate firebug.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the debug echo's are reached, then the point of failure would seem to be around the database connection, unless I'm missing something.

Check the connection details, and check you have the mysqli extension enabled.

Comment: If it were a connection problem, would it not display the error from die? If mysqli were not enabled, would that not give an error in the error log?

Comment: @Josh you don't have an or die() catch on your connection attempt. You should.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, surely the line after echo test con would catch any connection errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue where I would inexplicably get a blank page, usually in IE6 but sometimes in other browsers. It turned out to be a character encoding problem. I was outputting some strange characters, and the browsers were guessing what the encoding was based on the content. I fixed it by explicitly setting this header:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Calling this page directly from a
>   browser with `?cmd&id=1` should return

What do you mean by "return"?  From what I can see of your code, you need `?cmd=`**`GetSALEData`** or else a blank page will be returned, because everything is wrapped inside of the `if($cmd=="GetSALEData")` statement.

**Correction**: You should see "`test contest charset`" if your query string has `cmd` set to something other than "GetSALEData".  (Those two tests were added to the code later.)

Comment: echo "Test Con"; is not within the condition.

Comment: Perhaps "Community Code" would be a nice feature to StackOverflow.

Comment: ?cmd=blah still outputs nothing. By return I meant output or display to the browser.

Comment: ?cmd=blah doesn't even output the "test contest charset" code??  If you just put echo "hello world" as the first line of the file, do you even see that??

Comment: @Kip: nope. The only output I get is by omitting a cmd paramter

Answer (score 0):

```
$getHtml->bind_param("s", $id);
```

I don't know if this would cause the error, but shouldn't that and the getRecords bind_param have "i" as the first parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Put parentheses around your if-else
   statements. I have a feeling the person who
   edited your code may have "fixed" a
   potential problem there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good suggestions here for trying.  The one that I didn't see yet is to make sure there is enough memory allocated to PHP.  The folks over are [drupal.org](http://drupal.org) have a good break down of the [ways to increase PHP's memory allocation](http://drupal.org/node/207036).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because your server config is set to not display errors, so  your script is relying on executing that `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - this should work fine as long as the `error_reporting()` function gets executed. However, **if there is a parse error, the `error_reporting(E_ALL)` won't get executed**, and there foreyou will not see an error as the php.ini error reporting settings never get overwritten.

The only solution for you is to set error_reporting in a higher places such as htaccess or php.ini. But now at least you know that a blankpage = a parse error!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have no error and keep getting a blank page, I would suggest you install php-process.

```
yum -y install php-process
```

In other cases, you get such an error if you do not have pear installed.

`yum -y install php-pear php-pear-DB` or just to install the db `pear install DB`

Hope this helps someone with the blank page issue.

Comment: If you are going to recommend a tool to debug an issue you should also include a little about what it offers as well as how to use if for the purpose you suggest. Also, the OP never mentioned that they were using Linux so an OS agnostic solution might be more appropriate.